# spring 3.1: jdbcTemplate auto commit to false.

Tags: transactions, jdbctemplate, autocommit

Hi Is their a way to set autocommit to false in spring jdbctemplate.

The thing is instead of transaction (where their is rollback option), I want to have query committed at end of transaction.

So instead of

insert --> commit --> rollback.

I want insert --> fail --> (no commit).

Answer (score 6):

I did not understand your whole question, but I can answer the first part: *Is there a way to set autocommit to false in spring jdbctemplate?*

The autocommit configuration is normally set on the connection itself. The `Connection` is created by the `Datasource`. As the `JdbcTemplate` does not have an option to manually disable auto commit in the connections it requests to the Datasource, the way to achieve this is using a `Datasource` that creates connections with `autocommit` set to `false` by default.

This example configuration using apache commons `BasicDataSource` achieves that:

```xml
<bean id="database" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            ...
            <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
            ...
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to catch your question, and there are some ideas to solve them.
The way set `autocommit` to `false` in spring `jdbctemplate`:

1. Set `defaultAutoCommit` property of `DataSource` to `false`.
2. You can commit or rollback by writing codes as below:

   ```
   jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection.commit();
   jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection.rollback();
   ```