# SQL DELETE FROM by JdbcTemplate doesn't work

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm trying to delete a row from a table using JDBC template but somehow it just doesn't work, no errors just nothing. The Insert Into works just fine with almost same logic.

```
@Override
  public void deleteEntry(long id) {
    String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM company WHERE id = ?";
    jdbcTemplate.update(deleteQuery, id);
  }
```

and for example, the working sniped

```
@Override
public long addEntry(Company entry) {
    String insertSql = "INSERT INTO company VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    jdbcTemplate.update(insertSql, companyObject(entry));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm really confused at the moment so if you have any idea that will be great.

Comment: You code looks ok. Your problem is elsewhere. E.g. are you sure you call method with correct `id` value? Are you sure you're *committing* the change?

Comment: Isn't JDBC connections start out with auto-commit mode enabled?

Comment: I have no idea how you manage your connection and your transactions, so I commented on a *potential* cause of your problem. Don't you use Spring transactions, to ensure that if/when you do multiple related changes, they are committed or rollback as a group?

Comment: Have you traced the `int` value returned by `update`? It should report the number of records affected by the DELETE, so if it was 0, then you should pay attention to the value of the ID (as @Andreas suggested).

Comment: I would recommend you to print the value of the `id` that you pass in to the function `deleteEntry`. Print the value to check it is passing the value correctly

Answer (score 1):

The [`update`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method of `JdbcTemplate` has one return parameter giving *the number of rows affected*
so there is no exception if you delete nothing. You must check the return value with your expected count.

Here a small example in a pseudocode

```
def id = 1 
String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM company WHERE id = ?";
def updCnt = jdbcTemplate.update(deleteQuery, id);
println "deleting ID ${id}, deleted rows ${updCnt}"
```

gives e.g.

```
deleting ID 1, deleted rows 1
```

The most probable couse of *not deleteting* is that you use a non existing ID and the returned value is zero.

If you observe the expected deleted count but the record is not deleted, your DataSource is probably configured with `autoCommit FALSE` setting. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197774/how-to-set-autocommit-to-false-in-spring-jdbc-template?answertab=votes#tab-top) the details.