# How do I set Auto Commit false in SpringBoot application using JDBC template or JPA

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to use Spring Boot Application, where I am doing Spring Batch for bulk insert into DB using JDBCTemplate. The performance is very slow due to Auto Commit true default in Spring JDBC setting.

How to set Auto Commit false in Spring Boot JDBCTemplate configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set autocommit to false in spring jdbc template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197774/how-to-set-autocommit-to-false-in-spring-jdbc-template)

Comment: @mohammedkhan, no is not duplucate (conf in springboot!!!)